# Using an HD monitor as a TV for wii/ps3

Tags: display, graphics-card

I'm buying [this hd monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001P5CAV6) and (maybe) [this graphics card](http://www.pcgameshardware.com/aid,657567/Geforce-9400-GT-reviewed/Reviews/).

Maybe other graphics cards (the ones with TV input) allow the connection of peripherals?

If not, how can I use the monitor as a TV to receive input from a wii/ps3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that this is normally and easily done is through a monitor that has multiple inputs.  This monitor you have linked to just has an analog 15pin (blue, older monitor connector), and a digital DVD-D (usualy white, newer monitor connection).  This would allow you to hook up two computers or a computer and something else.  This monitor you linked to would not be ideal for what you want if you want the wii/ps3/computer hooked up all at once.  You need a monitor that has hdmi, composite HD, or composite input options along with the normal analog and digital dvi connections.

I, for instance, use a dell 2709w that has 9 different input options so i can connect all kinds of things to it and just switch the input selection on the monitor to go to it.

So you connect all the devices to your monitor and just switch between them on the monitor.  No need to run any of them through a video card.

And just a note, that video card is pretty basic.  It would work great in a computer that did not play games or edit video, but if you do, definatly look at something else.

One of the easiest places to look through monitors based on features is newegg.com. It can at least give you an idea of what is out there.  I personaly like Dell's Ultrasharp LCD's, but that is my opinion and they are not cheap monitors.

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/category.aspx?c=us&category_id=4009&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs

http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=20&name=LCD-Monitors#

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only buy the monitor I linked. I'm not in the US and I can't get it through Amazon. I know the video card I linked is pretty basic, but I'm no PC gamer so its ok. I noticed the card I linked is HDCP compliant, would that allow me to plug the wii or ps3? (not both at once)

Comment: @omgzor you shouldn't ask questions in comments. And you don't connect a game console to a pc graphics card. You connect a console or a pc graphics card to a monitor / tv / projector / etc.